# How to check list object has null value or empty string?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a Book class and then I make a `List<Book>`. I have a problem with checking all attributes. The following is an example of program code for a `class Book` :

```
class Book {  
    int id;  
    String name,author;
    public Book(int id, String name, String author) {  
        this.id = id;  
        this.name = name;  
        this.author = author;  
    }   
}
```

Here's the code snippet on the `List<Book>` :

```
 Book b = new Book(1, "", "Ok");
 Book c = new Book(2, "Z", "");
 Book d = new Book(0, "C", "Ok");
 List<Book> x = new ArrayList<>();
 x.add(b);
 x.add(c);
 x.add(d);
```

How to check if a value is **string empty** or **null** in a `List<Book>` and then return Boolean & return message example `id 2 has empty value`?

Comment: What is `Book d = new Book(, "C", "Ok");`? How it compiles?

Comment: just example @AlexeyR.

Comment: Example has to be representative and reproducible.

Comment: ok I'm sorry @AlexeyR.

Comment: Field `id` is a primitive `int` and therefore cannot be `null`

Comment: @senaa What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `StringUtils.isEmpty(...)` method from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-), or if you don't want the dependency you can write it your on like this:

```java
public static boolean isEmpty(String s) {
  return s == null || s.isEmpty();
}
```

To check all `authors` in the `List` use Streams:

```java
public boolean anyAuthorEmpty(List<Book> books) {
  return books.stream().anyMatch(b -> isEmpty(b.getAuthor());
}
```

To find the exact `Book` you can use `.findFirst()` like this:

```java
public Book findBookWithEmptyAuthor(List<Book> books) {
  return books.stream().filter(b -> isEmpty(b.getAuthor())
                .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

This will return the `Book` or `null` if none found.

If you need all with no author you can use `Collectors.toList()`:

```java
public List<Book> findBooksWithNoAuthor(List<Book> books) {
  return books.stream().filter(b -> isEmpty(b.getAuthor())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The requirement is to return exactly which objects have empty `author`. You will need to add that piece too.

Comment: is there any other way without calling the attributes one by one? @csalmhof

Comment: yes it's true what you said @SreeKumar

Comment: @senaa You can use multiple filters or filter for more values in e.g. a method `findBooksWithEmptyValue(List<Book> books)`. Then the filter would look like `.filter(b -> (isEmpty(b.getAuthor() || isEmpty(b.getName()))`. But then you loose the information, which field was empty. If you want to general check if any String-Field is null or empty you should go with reflection as @alexey-r mentiononed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70123755/9901515).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use Java Stream perhaps

```
public class Test1 {
    private Test1()
    {
        Book b = new Book(1, "", "Ok");
        Book c = new Book(2, "Z", "");
        Book d = new Book(3, "C", "Ok");
        List<Book> x = new ArrayList<>();
        x.add(b);
        x.add(c);
        x.add(d);
        
        boolean empty = x.stream()
                .filter(book -> book.name == null || book.name.isEmpty() || book.author == null || book.author.isEmpty())
                .count() > 0;
    }

    class Book
    {
        int id;
        String name, author;

        public Book(int id, String name, String author)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.author = author;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Mr Eddy, is there any other way without calling the attributes one by one?

Comment: Yes with Java reflection or with a new method in Book class which can test all the string of the current book, then you will juste have to call it for each book object to check if there is a Book with an empty String

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection so that you do not need to manually test each filed separately:

```java
static void testAllFieldsForNull(List<Book> bookList) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++){
        Book book = bookList.get(i);
        Field[] fields = book.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field field: fields){
            Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
            if(!fieldType.isPrimitive()){
                if (field.get(book) == null){
                    System.out.println("Field [" + field.getName() + "] has null value for book at position " + i);
                    continue;
                }
                if(fieldType.isAssignableFrom(String.class) && ((String)field.get(book)).isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println("Field [" + field.getName() + "] is empty String for book at position " + i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Book b = new Book(1, "", "Ok");
    Book c = new Book(2, "Z", "");
    Book d = new Book(0, "C", null);
    List<Book> x = new ArrayList<>();
    x.add(b);
    x.add(c);
    x.add(d);
    testAllFieldsForNull(x);
}
```

Output:

```
Field [name] is empty String for book at position 0
Field [author] is empty String for book at position 1
Field [author] has null value for book at position 2
```

OR if you need to just collect "good" books (actually any sort of oject) you can use:

```java
public static boolean testObject(Object obj){
    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    boolean okay = true;
    for(Field field: fields){
        Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
        try{
            if(!fieldType.isPrimitive()){
                if (field.get(obj) == null){
                    okay = false;
                    continue;
                }
                if(fieldType.isAssignableFrom(String.class) && ((String)field.get(obj)).isEmpty()){
                    okay = false;
                }
            }
        }catch (IllegalAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return okay;
}
```

and then use that for filtering:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Book b = new Book(1, "", "Ok");
    Book c = new Book(2, "Z", "");
    Book d = new Book(0, "C", null);
    Book a = new Book(3, "C", "D");
    List<Book> x = new ArrayList<>();
    x.add(b);
    x.add(c);
    x.add(d);
    x.add(a);
    System.out.println(
            x
            .stream()
            .filter(FieldTest::testObject)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0).id
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To check multiple attributes of the class `Book` the following solution ,may be offered (providing that there is implementation of the helper method `isNullOrEmpty`):

```java
class SONullEmpty {
    static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) {
        return str == null || str.isEmpty();
    }

    static List<Book> booksWithNullOrEmpty(List<Book> books) {
        return books
            .stream()
            .filter(book -> Stream.of(
                    book.getName(), book.getAuthor()
                ).anyMatch(SONullEmpty::isNullOrEmpty)
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

---

Similarly, a method accepting multiple getters of the `Book` attributes may be implemented and then called:

```java
// in the same SONullEmpty class
static List<Book> withNullOrEmptyAttribs(List<Book> books, Function<Book, String> ... getters) {
    return books
        .stream()
        .filter(book -> Arrays.stream(getters).anyMatch(g -> isNullOrEmpty(g.apply(book))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Test:

```java
Book b = new Book(1, "", "Ok");
Book c = new Book(2, "Z", "");
Book d = new Book(3, null, "Ok");
List<Book> x = Arrays.asList(b, c, d);

withNullOrEmptyAttribs(x, Book::getName)
    .forEach(book -> System.out.printf("Book with id=%d has null or empty name%n", book.getId()));

withNullOrEmptyAttribs(x, Book::getAuthor)
    .forEach(book -> System.out.printf("Book with id=%d has null or empty author%n", book.getId()));
```

Output:

```
Book with id=1 has null or empty name
Book with id=3 has null or empty name
Book with id=2 has null or empty author
```